# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have installed pandas but I still have trouble using reset_drop...any idea what the problem is?!
recently I've been using   and dataframing and I have trouble using reset_drop code the result is

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'reset_index'
```

Comment: There is no method named `reset_drop` in pandas...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is `reset_drop` in pandas, but if you want to reset the index you can use `df.reset_index(drop=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a pandas function on a numpy array. You have to call it on an instance of `pandas.DataFrame`.

The name of the function is also `reset_index` and it is used as `your_dataframe.reset_index(drop=True)`